# what is corresponding java data type of wchar_t

Tags: java

I used wchar_t data type for reading Hindi character using C I/O
now I want to convert this C program into Java..
I am doing conversion line by line..
but now I am not getting what is name of data type in Java for wchar_t in c??

Answer (score 3):

In Java, [all strings are Unicode-16 by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).  The equivalent of a `wchar_t` in Java is simply `char`.

The [same is true for C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay(v=vs.71).aspx) as well.

Comment: This doesn't handle characters that aren't in the Basic Multilingual Plane (including most emoji), because those are each two code units in UTF-16. wchar_t is usually 32 bits.

Comment: That may be, and for some characters UTF-16 does require two positions.  In C# and Java, that is all hidden from the user.  Java was written at a time when Unicode fit inside 16 bits.  There are new APIs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Java's char type is 16 bits. [Basic Hindi characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_(Unicode_block)) will always be one char each, but archaic scripts and emoji may be two chars each. To deal with these, the int type is used. `CharSequence.codePoints()` converts a string or other CharSequence to a UTF-32 IntStream, which in turn has `toIntArray()`. To convert back to a String, use the `String(int[],int,int)` constructor.